# How to find the base class which called the Decoder initialiser

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nscoder

I have a BaseView class which is inherited from UIView like:

```
@IBDesignable class BaseView: UIView {
 override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
   }

 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
   }
}
```

I set this class for `UILabel`, `UIButton` and `UITextField` in storyboard.

Now, I have to recognise that which one of the `UILabel`, `UIButton` or `UITextField` is called the `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`.

Is there anyway around this issue?

**Update:**

It seems that it's not possible to set custom class of type UIView to UILabel so there is no way around this issue.

Comment: you can use the tag value, and check in your initi with coder

Comment: but anyway iam not sure about your approach, because the UILabel is a subclass of UIView already

Comment: well, the ```self.viewWithTag( _tagNumber_ )``` is always nil. and the tag is always 0

Comment: and about the approach I have to say that, I want to changed some shared features between views like `UILable`, `UIButton` and ... in a base class and also by detecting the view change some specific features for each of them. that's why I have to detect the source view

Comment: Yes I catch your idea @Mina  but you can't change the UILabel parent class  so you must to implement your UILabel or UIButton or whatever you need, and about the tag i mean the .tag property with is in every UIView class, something like `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
   if(self.tag == 1){print("UILabel")}}`

Comment: I've set the tag for the view but when I want to retrieve a view from tag the result is nil. ```self.viewWithTag(10)``` it returns a view but `self.viewWithTag(10) as? UILabel` is nil.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to test the class

```
if self is UILabel { }
```

But I get a compiler warning that cast from BaseView to unrelated UILabel always fail

```
if (self as UIView) is UILabel { }
```

clears the warning but is of no use.

So a question: you said "*I set this class for UILabel, UIButton and UITextField in storyboard*"

Could you detail what you did ?

How do you declare the IBOutlet ? BaseView ? What type do you assign in IB to the label ?
Because BaseView is not a subclass of UILabel, I could not declare the label as BaseView ?

Comment: and the result of the `if (self as UIView) is UILabel` is always nil.

Comment: Yes. When loading the IBOutlet var labelView: BaseView! : if BaseView is declared as subclass of UILabel, we go through the init?(coder) ; if it is declared as subclass of UIView, not. But then, I changed again declaration of BaseView as UIView ; I get a warning, but it compiles and it goes through the init?(coder) ; I've included a print("From init(coder)") to check.

Comment: Could you explain how you "set this class for UILabel, UIButton and UITextField in storyboard"

Comment: When I set the BaseView as a custom class for UILabel it was inhertited from UILabel and after that I change the BaseView and changed nothing in storyboard, based on this scenario the decoder init was still called.

Comment: I feel we are somehow "cheating" the system doing so, as what is declared in code and in IB are not consistent. Finally, I think the only solution is to create a subclass for each: UILabel, UIButton, UITextField, as someone proposed earlier.

Comment: Yeah, I had seperate subclasses for each of them, I was thinking about having all of them in one. And finally findout there is no way.